# Rust / Prost : How do add Debug to structs & unions?

Tags: rust, protocol-buffers, prost

It looks like the prost protobuf generator only adds `derive(Debug)` to generated enum types (and only enums not inside a `pub mod` block). None of the generated structs, or unions have it applied. How can I get prost to add it to everything?

Using Prost version 0.9 and rustic 1.56

Comment: I don't see the logic in trying to implement `Debug` on a `union` safely.

Comment: I meant union in the protobuf, not rust. I don't think prost generates rust unions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prost does derive Debug on everything. But you need `prost::Messaeg` in scope or you'll get an error about missing Debug traits.

Comment: could you please elaborate on this more?

Answer (score -1):

`prost` doesn't have an option to turn that on so you have to do it yourself.

If you want to implement a trait for a type. You need to have either the trait or the type in your library/binary.

Since the trait is in `std` and the type is in an external crate the best you can do is create a unit struct to wrap the type. Then implement `Debug` for that.

```rust
use std::fmt;

struct DebugStruct(NonDebugEnum);

impl fmt::Debug for DebugStruct {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        todo!()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let wrapped = DebugStruct(NonDebugEnum::Example);
    println!("{:?}", wrapped);
}
```

You will have to come up with the actual logic of how to format it.

Comment: So I have to add all the fields manually? And if the protobuf ever changes, I either won't compile anymore or no longer be complete?

Comment: Yes pretty much. Or you can ask the developers of the crate to add that functionality. It isn't a very nice situation either way.